# Add View To View Without XML

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this class that extends View (it's in C# because I use Xamarin)

```
public class ScannerOverlay : View
{

    public ScannerOverlay(Context context) : base(context)
    {
       //Initializing some values here
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        //Draw some stuff on the canvas
    }
}
```

I create this view using: `View v = new ScannerOverlay(context);`

Now I want to add a button to this view. How do I do this? The view has no layout whatsoever so AddView() is not going to work. And from what I found it's not possible to draw a button on a canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by extending from `RelativeLayout` instead of `View`.

If (like in my case) the OnDraw Method is not getting called, set the following in the constructor: `this.SetWillNotDraw(false);`

Comment: Is it the answer for the question?

Comment: @deadfish Yes, but I can't accept it because Stackoverflow says 
>You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't add a `View` to another `View`.

**Hard Way:** You can create a `View` as if it has many Views inside it, but you should draw them manually using `Canvas` and `Paint`, also handle the click based on touch location of that each "fake" `View`. So it will take you a lot of time. This is called **Custom View**.

**Easy Way:** You can add any `View` to a `ViewGroup` and any child of `ViewGroup` like `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, and `RelativeLayout` with `ViewGroup.AddView(view)` function. This is called **Compound View**.

Answer (score 0):

ViewGroup extends View so you directly get all features of View event though you extend ViewGroup. In this way you can add new View to CustomView directly.

```
public class ScannerOverlay : ViewGroup
{

    public ScannerOverlay(Context context) : base(context)
    {
       //Initializing some values here
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        //Draw some stuff on the canvas
    }
}
```